# New image field type for Articles only displaying on the article node itself, not on taxonomy or custom view pages

Tags: entities

I am having some issues with custom field content only displaying on the individual node. I have created a new field called field_second_image for the Article content type. I am calling it right under the regular field_image with print render($content['field_second_image']); in my node--article.tpl.php file. On the actual article node both images display properly. However, on a taxonomy list page or the custom article view page I have created, the second image does not show up. I think this relates to the general issue I've been having getting custom field content to display on pages other than the individual node page. Is there something I'm completely missing about getting this content to appear on other pages? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the concept is `view_modes`. [See this documentation page as an introduction](http://drupal.org/node/1577752).

`node--article.tpl.php` is used to show the `Default` view mode of a node. The related taxonomy page(s) for terms lists content out by default using the `Teaser` mode. This view mode is usually a succinct version of your complete node fields (sometimes showing a body teaser, and fewer fields).

Some modules to help you create new "view modes" of your content and easily customize how and what is shown are for instance (a small example list, by NO MEANS all of the possabilities, nor are these necessarily the best options):

- [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds)
- [Entity View Modes](http://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode)
- [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels)
- [Custom Formatters](http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters)

Comment: I see, well thank you very much those links should be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

@Tenken the solution actually ended up being much simpler. I just had to go under the Manage Display tab and enable the new field to be visible in the teaser. Thanks for those links though I think they'll prove useful in the future.